# Save Outlook attached PDF to temp filder via Drag and Drop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, outlook

I'm looking for a way to save a PDF file from an Outlook Mail to a the Temp folder of the user to work with it.

I did this some time back in C#, but it seems like VBA cant handle the Drag and Drop with outlook Files.

So I have a UserForm in my Excel file. In this Form is a ListView. I can Drag and Drop files From the explorer write the path of the file into a sheet.
So I want to do the same with an PDF File from an attachment from Outlook. But I cant find a way to save the PDF to a folder.

Is there a way to do this with the Drag and Drop event from the ListView?

Comment: What is drag and drop? As far as I know that is a human interface thing, nothing that happens in the background. In the background it's a copy or move

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop decrease automation quality. But i have used a macro to retrieve emails with attachments before. I put it for you hope to be usefull

```
Sub GetAttachments()
Dim oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMAPIFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim oNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim iCnt As Integer, RowCnt As Integer
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet

Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
Set oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oMailItem = oApp.CreateItem(0)
Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet
RowCnt = 2

For Each oFolder In oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders
    Set oMAPIFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders(oFolder.Name)
    For iCnt = 1 To oMAPIFolder.Items.Count
        '..... In this section you can put another if to check emails within special date condition.
        If TypeOf oMAPIFolder.Items(iCnt) Is MailItem Then
            '......... this message has attchment. you can check if it is pdf or not.
            Set oMailItem = oMAPIFolder.Items(iCnt)
            If oMailItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                With DataSheet
                    .Cells(RowCnt, 2) = oMailItem.Subject
                    .Cells(RowCnt, 3) = oMailItem.Sender.Address
                    .Cells(RowCnt, 4) = oMailItem.ReceivedTime
                    .Cells(RowCnt, 1) = oMailItem.Attachments.Item(1).Filename
                    RowCnt = RowCnt + 1
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next iCnt
Next

Set oApp = Nothing
Set oNS = Nothing
Set oMailItem = Nothing
Set oMAPIFolder = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```